# Why doesn't static_cast work when I divide two integers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-cast

This question is about C++ code. I have two integers a and b, and I want to divide one by the other and store the answer as a double. But when I enter the following code:

```
int a = 3, b = 7;
double d = static_cast<double>(a/b);
cout<<d<<endl;
```

I get 0. I don't understand why. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause you're still dividing two `ints`. The result is still an `int` (0), then you cast that `int` to a `double` and print it. Try casting one of the operands first, then dividing.